# How to make other boxes close when one is enlarged in jQuery gridly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the fiddle whose modification I need: http://jsfiddle.net/wp2E4/

So when we click on a box, it expands. When we click on another box, it expands too. But, what I need is that when one box is clicked and there is an expanded box already, the previously expanded box should contract, i.e. there must be only one expanded box at a time.

Talking in terms of classes, when there is already a **large** `div` then, on clicking on a **small** `div`, the **large** `div` should close down.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.brick').click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($($this).hasClass("large")) {} else {
        if ($(".gridly").find(".large").length > 0) {
            var large = $(".gridly").find(".large");
            $(large).toggleClass("large small");
            size = 140;
            $(large).data('width', size);
            $(large).data('height', size);
        }
    }
    $this.toggleClass('large small');
    size = $this.hasClass('small') ? 140 : 300;
    $this.data('width', size);
    $this.data('height', size);
    return $('.gridly').gridly('layout');
});
```

**[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wp2E4/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/zBaRr/2/)

You'll need to update the other `.bricks` on click

```
var _collapse = ($this.hasClass('large')) ? 1 : 0;

if (_collapse > 0) {
    $this.removeClass('large')
        .addClass('small')
        .data('width', 300)
        .data('height', 300);
} else {
    $('.brick.large')
        .removeClass('large')
        .addClass('small')
        .data('width', 140)
        .data('height', 140);
    $this.toggleClass('large').toggleClass('small');
}
```

Comment: Maybe select only the large bricks? `$('.brick.large')`

Comment: There's a small problem with your code. When only one brick is `large` then it doesn't close. Other than that, everything works!

Comment: Awesome! Working now.